# VBA - i cannot see result of autofilter (like not apply/ok button pressed)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to filter range by 2 dates.
I see that filter is set correctly in filter parameters, but only when i press OK button i can see filtering result on my table .. anyone know why ?

```
Sub Pofiltrujodnajnowszejdaty()

Set First_Cell = Worksheets("Schedule RA_RB").Range("B2")
Set Starting_Date = Range("J1")
Set Ending_Date = Range("K1")
Field = 2

First_Cell.AutoFilter Field:=Field, Criteria1:=">" & Starting_Date, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Ending_Date

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the **numeric values of the dates** - this is always the case if you are not working on an english system:

```vb
First_Cell.AutoFilter Field:=Field, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(Starting_Date), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(Ending_Date)
```